# Android: How to make position of View match the visual representation after animation

Tags: android, animation, view, imageview, sequence

I am currently trying to animate a card game using an AnimationSet of Translate and Rotate animations. Although I am using setFillAfter(true) and see the card visibly move and stay in it's new position, the actual position of the ImageView is still at it's old location.

In the Google documentation it says:

Note: Regardless of how your animation may move or resize, the bounds of the View that holds your animation will not automatically adjust to accommodate it. Even so, the animation will still be drawn beyond the bounds of its View and will not be clipped. However, clipping will occur if the animation exceeds the bounds of the parent View.

This means that all of my old onClickListeners, etc are still being associated with the old position rather than the newly updated visual representation, and any new animation applied to the View occur from the initial spot, not the newly located one.

What is the best way to get the effect that I seek (a card sliding from my hand to the center of the screen, which is a different LinearLayout, and then in a later sequence sliding from that spot off the screen)?

I know what I seek is possible as the people at bytesequencing.com have accomplished this smooth animation effect in their android game "Hearts! (free)" which I discovered in the market.

Thanks!

Comment: You could build a LayoutParams object with the info that describes the new position, and then pass it to view.setLayoutParams().

Comment: Only this would not accomplish an animation as desired and would be overly verbose as the entire layout of the activity would need to be recreated since the ImageView slides into a different LinearLayout section of our "table" layout.

Comment: You do it from the onAnimationEnd() inside of a listener that you attach to your Animation. And you wouldn't need to redo the whole activity, just the imageView you're using. Layout.removeView(yourImageView) and otherLayout.addView(yourImageView) is what you'd use to get it from one layout to another. Its probably not the cleanest way to handle this situation. But I have a project which is animating an ImageView in a similar fashion and this is how I accomplished it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Tim.  I will try an experiment to see how this works.  When you addView, how do you add it to the exact coordinates where the animation ended? Also, does this not produce a visible flicker, or is it seemingly smooth?

Comment: you'll have to create your LayoutParams object to place the view in the same spot where the view is when the animation is complete. Then call .setLayoutParams(), and then layout.addView(). It doesn't create a noticeable flicker effect for me.

Comment: Yeah, programmatically though how do you figure out where this "same spot" actually is.  I can't seem to find a way of getting the ending location such that I can set the LayoutParams accurately.

Comment: I also seem to be having multiple other issues with this solution.  The first being that the animation doesn't seem to be allowed to cross it's parent's boundary.  Do you know how to get it get it to view above the other layouts when it crosses the threshold?

Comment: Second, the removeView and addView are throwing errors.

Comment: Specifically, removeView throws a null pointer exception, even though I can use the ImageView to add listeners to it, etc.  And if I try to add this view to the other layout, I get an IllegalState exception with the error message telling me I need to call removeView on the parent first.

Comment: Could you perhaps send some example code of yours so I can see how I can hack this to get it working?

Comment: Yeah I'll get something together today and put it up here.

Comment: @BryanRichter--Princeton2013 Did you find a solution for this issue? Can you share an example to tackle this problem?

Comment: how to do swipe up to next item loading detailview like in newsinshorts android app.and how to move that view from below the actionbar icons.